# Fast search within strings in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, search

Which is the fastest way to search within string in PostgreSQL (case insensivity):

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE another_col ILIKE '%typed%'
```

or

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE another_col ~* 'typed'
```

How can I turn on showing the time which query need to return results? Something like is on default in mySQL (I am thinking about CLI client).

Answer (score 1):

Both queries are the same, PostgreSQL rewrites `ILIKE` to `~*`. Check the results from EXPLAIN to see this behaviour.

I'm not sure about your question, but the [psql-client](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) can show you some timing of the query, using `\timing`.

Comment: This is not the same.
If I write sth like that:
ilike '%[text]%' this not the same as ~* '[text]'. I think this is something with regex.

Comment: This example is different, you have to escape the brackets in the regex if you want to search for brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the timing:

One solution is to use the switch for psql that Frank has already mentioned.

When you use [EXPLAIN ANALZYE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) it also includes the total runtime of the query **on the server**.

I prefer this when comparing the runtime for different versions of a query as it removes the network from the equation.